# Receiving Syntax error. Extra ',' when adding OR( condition on validation rule

Tags: formula, validation-rule, validation

When writing the below validation rule for a custom object, I find that it works for the first half; however, I also need to at the OR( condition for specific Stage values. When I do so, I'm receiving the "Syntax error. Extra ','" message. Seeing what I'm doing incorrectly...

```
AND(
    ((LLC_BI__First_Payment_Date__c-45) > LLC_BI__CloseDate__c),
    NOT($Permission.Bypass_Validation_Rules),
    $User.No_Workflow__c = false
),
OR(
    ISPICKVAL(LLC_BI__Stage__c = "Processing"),
    ISPICKVAL(LLC_BI__Stage__c = "Doc Prep"),
    ISPICKVAL(LLC_BI__Stage__c = "Closing)"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've taken the liberty of formatting your question for you. Formatting the formula as if it were code.

In doing so, the problem becomes obvious (but still easy to miss if you've been staring at it for too long).

`ISPICKVAL(LLC_BI__Stage__c = "Closing)"`

has the double quote and close parenthesis switched. It should instead be

`ISPICKVAL(LLC_BI__Stage__c = "Closing")`

Beyond that though, your current formula results in two, unrelated boolean values. Validation rules require you to have a single boolean as a result. You likely intended for the `OR()` segment to be included in the overall `AND()`.

#### +edit:

And as living evidence of my comment about missing obvious things, I missed that you're also using `ISPICKVAL()` incorrectly.

`ISPICKVAL(LLC_BI__Stage__c = "Processing")` (and the like)

should instead be
`ISPICKVAL(LLC_BI__Stage__c, "Processing")`

`ISPICKVAL()` takes 2 arguments. The picklist to use, and the value to test against.

Comment: Thank you so much for formatting my question properly and for catching the parenthesis error (and for your kindness and patience with my noobie errors! I see what you're saying with the unrelated boolean results -- however, if I add the OR condition to be included in the overall AND(), would that make every part of the rule an OR?

Comment: @JRP Happens to the best of us. I don't care to recall how many times I've had 1-character errors that have taken me hours to days to realize.

Comment: @JRP Nope, using the `AND()` and `OR()` functions only applies the operation to the things inside of the parenthesis. So the result would be `close date > 45 days after first payment AND can't bypass AND do workflow AND (custom Stage is one of those 3 values)`. If that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you - when I add it like that, I'm getting an 'Error: Field LLC_BI__Stage__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.' message `AND(
OR(
((LLC_BI__First_Payment_Date__c-45) > LLC_BI__CloseDate__c),
NOT($Permission.Bypass_Validation_Rules),
$User.No_Workflow__c = false),
ISPICKVAL(LLC_BI__Stage__c = "Processing"),
ISPICKVAL(LLC_BI__Stage__c = "Doc Prep"),
ISPICKVAL(LLC_BI__Stage__c = "Closing")
  )
 )`   (sorry if not formatted correctly)

Comment: @JRP answer updated.

Comment: I saw your edit -- thank you again - it's currently working. Will takeaway a lot of lessons from this - truly appreciate it!